# How do I play a card if it has two colors within the one mana symbol in its cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have just bought a deck and it has cards that have two colors within one mana symbol, like [image]. Do I have to pay both colors or can I choose between the two?

Comment: If you had to pay both, they'd be side-by-side.

Answer (score 6):

Mana symbols such as [image] are called a hybrid mana cost. You can pay that cost with either of the 2 colors shown. Here is a brief summary of hybrid mana rules:

> Hybrid mana symbols represent a cost that can be paid with either of two colors. For example, a cost represented by the [image] symbol can be paid with one white mana or one blue mana. It’s both a white and a blue mana symbol, and a card with [image] in its mana cost is both white and blue.

Comment: I corrected an "oh1" to the same symbol; could you double check my correction in case that wasn't what it was supposed to refer to?

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks; I had made the same correction in another place but missed that one; it's correct now.